# Edit Box Callback not working On Change

Tags: c#, text, callback, outlook, vsto

I created a very simple edit box for an Outlook plugin. I am using VSTO. I cannot get the Message Box to popup when I type something into the edit box. From what I understand it should change when I add new text and hit enter or click somewhere else. I am probably missing something simple. I have looked at a lot of examples but they all seem to be a little different. Any help?

```
    public void editBox2_TextChanged(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("New Skill Added");
        //Code to Add Skills...
    }

    public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
    {
        this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
    }
```

Here is my xml.

```
    <group id="group3" label="Skills">
        <editBox id="editBox1" onChange="editBox1_TextChanged" label="Add Skills" showImage="false" />
    </group>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. I need to add another argument to the Text_Changed callback so it is like the following.

```
public void editBox2_TextChanged(Office.IRibbonControl control, String text)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("New Skill Added");
    //Code to Add Skills...
}
```